# How to fix: 'RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run().'

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow from this [website](https://learningtensorflow.com/variables/) and typed the below code from the same:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x+5, name='y')

model = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session :
  session.run(model)
  print(session.run(y))
```

I am getting an error as below:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are learning tf, why not start with tf2, instead of the 1.x

Anyway, here is your code

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()

x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.constant(5, name='y')
add = tf.add(x,y)

tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session :
  result = session.run(add)
  print(result)
```

Comment: Can you please point some nice tutorials that teach tf2 from the beginning?

Comment: there are a lot of free stuff here  https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/learn-ml  it is very nice ! thanks for accepting my answer